# tokenizer.push_to_hub(repo_name) is not working

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I'm trying to puch my tokonizer to my huggingface repo...
it consist of the model vocab.Json (I'm making a speech recognition model)
My code:

```
vocab_dict["|"] = vocab_dict[" "]
del vocab_dict[" "]
vocab_dict["[UNK]"] = len(vocab_dict)
vocab_dict["[PAD]"] = len(vocab_dict)
len(vocab_dict)
```

```
import json
with open('vocab.json', 'w') as vocab_file:
    json.dump(vocab_dict, vocab_file)
```

```
from transformers import Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer

tokenizer = Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer.from_pretrained("./", unk_token="[UNK]", pad_token="[PAD]", word_delimiter_token="|")
```

```
from huggingface_hub import login

login('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')
repo_name = "Foxasdf/ArabicTextToSpeech"
add_to_git_credential=True
tokenizer.push_to_hub(repo_name)
```

the tokenizer.push_to_hub(repo_name) is giving me this error:
**TypeError: create_repo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organization'**

I have logged in my huggingface account using
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
but the error is still the same..
here's a link of the my collab notebook you can see the full code there and the error: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11tkQ85SfaT6U_1PXDNwk0Q6qogw2r2sw?hl=ar&hl=en&authuser=0#scrollTo=WkbZ_Wcidq8Z

Comment: I added the notebook link so you can see the error there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. It is somehow associated with version of transformers - I have 4.6. When I change environment to the one with 4.11.3 transformers version the problem is that code tries to clone repository which I am going to yet create and there is an error " Remote repository not found ... "

Checked more and it looks like issue with version with huggingface_hub library - when it is downgraded to 0.10.1 it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, change the transformers library to version `4.24.0` with the command below:

```bash
pip install transformers==4.24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

These library versions worked for me:

```bash
!pip install transformers==4.24.0
!pip install huggingface_hub==0.11
```

Also make sure you are accessing after `notebook_login()` cell execution.